# CSS responsive issues on laptop and desktop

Tags: css, wordpress, plugins, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm trying to make my subscribe form responsive and inline with the contact form above it. This is what it looks currently with the laptop view. I was able to line it up accurately with the laptop, tablet, and mobile views. (First Screenshot)

But then I realized that the subscribe form is still longer on the desktop view. For some reason, the of 980px is too wide on the desktop view even though its the perfect fit on the laptop view which is a smaller screens size. (Second screenshot)

This has made adjusting the media query a little difficult. Can anyone make any recommendations in this situation?

[image]

[image]

```
<style>

  .mc4wp-form {
    margin: 0 auto; !important;
    max-width: 990px; !important;
    text-align: center;
}


  /*Media Queries below */


   /*FOR DESKTOP */
   @media screen and (max-width: 1400px) {
   .mc4wp-form {
      margin: 0 auto;
      text-align: center;
      width: 85%; !important;
      margin-top: 0;
  }


     /*FOR LAPTOP */
   @media screen and (max-width: 1295px) {
   .mc4wp-form {
      margin: 0 auto;
      text-align: center;
      width: 30%; !important;
      margin-top: 0;
  }


   /*FOR TABLET AND MOBILE */  
  @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .mc4wp-form {
      margin: 0 auto;
      text-align: center;
      width: 100%; !important;
      margin-top: 0;
  }



</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.mc4wp-form {
    margin: 0 auto; !important;
    max-width: 990px; !important;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Looks like you have a syntax issue. There shouldn't be semi-colons after "auto" and "990px". You'll see the Chrome inspector throw a syntax warning in the console.

Revised:

```
.mc4wp-form {
    margin: 0 auto !important;
    max-width: 990px !important;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for  responding! Unfortunately the form is still longer on the desktop. I also noticed that I had  the desktop media query set to "min-width" when it was supposed to be "max", my apologies. Even after fixing it it still didn't work.

Comment: `<div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-2">
<div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-8">
<div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-2">` Looking more closely at the site, I noticed for the form above it has this 3 column layout pattern. Where the form in the center is col-sm-8. Can you mimic that same layout behavior from above? Might be easier.

Comment: Just playing with the inspector on that website if you just set the `max-width` to 1350px that seems to do the trick. When I go to the site I'm actually seeing your form smaller than the form above it. Not wider like that screenshot shows. Careful using too many `!important` in CSS. It should be used sparingly.